# How to retry Ajax call using reference with Success and Failure handlers

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to see if it is possible to store the reference to an ajax call on failure, and then retry the call later. I have tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "controller/action",
    data: {
        params: "here"
    }
})
.success(function (response) {
    DoStuffHere();
})
.fail(function (error) {
    ajaxRef = this;
    DoOtherStuff();
})
```

Where DoOtherStuff attempts to make the ajax call using the reference as follows:

```
function DoOtherStuff() {
    if(ajaxRef)
    {
        $.ajax(ajaxRef);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is oversimplified to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

It seems that this actually does make the ajax call, but the problem is that it doesn't seem to keep a reference to the `success` or `fail` attributes of the call. So when the call comes back successfully, it doesn't call `DoStuffHere();`

In my searching for an answer to this question, I found code that says that it works if you call `$.ajax(this)` inside the `success` or `fail` function, but in my case, I need to run certain other functions and ajax calls prior to retrying.

Is there any way to make it so that the `success` and `fail` are carried with the reference to the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried attaching the succes/failure handlers to the ajax request object itself?
Something like this:

```
var ajaxRef = {
    url: "controller/action",
    data: {
        params: "here"
    },
    success: ajaxSuccess,
    error: ajaxFailure
}

$.ajax(ajaxRef)

function ajaxSuccess(response){
    DoStuffHere();
}
function ajaxFailure(error){
    DoOtherStuff();
}

function DoOtherStuff() {
    if(ajaxRef)
    {
        $.ajax(ajaxRef);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like I was typing my answer the same time as you were typing yours. So I accepted yours as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out why this wasn't working. I'm not sure why I've learned to use the `.success()` and `.fail()` handlers for ajax, but apparently they don't stick around with the reference that way. So when I change the code to the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "controller/action",
    data: {
        params: "here"
    },
    success: function (response) {
        DoStuffHere();
    },
    error: function (error) {
        ajaxRef = this;
        DoOtherStuff();
    }
})
```

Then this actually works:

```
function DoOtherStuff() {
    if(ajaxRef) {
        $.ajax(ajaxRef);
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful to someone out there!

Comment: @Manuel Otto came to the same conclusion as I did. Thank you!